# PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - gantry plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I got this error log few days ago

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/karatm/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gantry/bugfixes.php on line 52<br>
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/karatm/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gantry/bugfixes.php on line 52<br>
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/karatm/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gantry/bugfixes.php on line 102<br>
```

**This is line 52 from bugfixes.php:**

```
foreach($sidebar_contents as $sidebar_contents_id => &$sidebar_widget_instance)
```

**This is line 102 from bugfixes.php:**

```
foreach ($override_sidebar as $position => &$sbw_instances)
```

What this error mean, how can i fix this ?

(if someone can help me, i can send him the full .php file)

Thanks

Comment: I would say that you don't have anything in the sidebar and that's why. This is probably just bad coding from the developer of the plugin.

Comment: That's ironic: bugs in `bugfixes.php`. I wonder shouldn't that session at least process that case properly (i.e., checking for $sidebar_contents actually being an array?)

Answer (score 0):

foreach ($override_sidebar as $position => &$sbw_instances)
try to remove & 
try this 
foreach ($override_sidebar as $position => $sbw_instances)